# Query is either selecting too many fields or the filter conditions are too complicated

Tags: apex, batch

How to select deal with this issue

```
GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
string fieldStr = '';
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = GlobalDescribeMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();
Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > objectFields = objResult.fields.getMap();
fieldSet = new Set < string > (objectFields.keyset());
fieldAnalysisList = [select id, name, Populated_On__c, Type__c
    from Field_Analysis__c where Object_Analysis__c =: objForAnalysisID
];
for (Field_Analysis__c fldA: fieldAnalysisList) {
    if (fieldSet.contains(fldA.name)) {
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.put(fldA.name, fldA);
    } else {
        fieldAnalysisListToDel.add(fldA);
    }
}
for (Schema.SObjectField fieldToken: objectFields.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dr = fieldToken.getDescribe();
    fieldStr += dr.getName() + ',';
    if (!fieldAnalysisOldMap.containskey(dr.getName())) {
        Field_Analysis__c fa = new Field_Analysis__c();
        fa.name = dr.getName();
        fa.Label__c = dr.getLabel();
        fa.Type__c = string.valueof(dr.getType());
        fa.Populated_On__c = 0;
        fa.Object_Analysis__c = objForAnalysis.id;
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.put(dr.getName(), fa);
    } else {
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.get(dr.getName()).Populated_On__c = 0;
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.get(dr.getName()).Label__c = dr.getLabel();
        fieldAnalysisOldMap.get(dr.getName()).Type__c = string.valueof(dr.getType());
    }
}
fieldStr = fieldStr.substring(0, fieldStr.length() - 1);
String[] fieldArray = fieldStr.split(',');
List < String > fieldList = new List < String > ();
string queryStr = 'select ' + fieldStr + ' from ' + objectName;
return Database.getQueryLocator(queryStr);
```

Comment: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176969&language=en_US

Comment: Hi Larson...
Could you please provide me any reference example???
Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you really need every single field? There is a reason `Salesforce` refused to implement `SELECT *` functionality.

Comment: Yes...here we are exporting all the metadata information to Excel sheet...so we need to query every field.

Comment: Are you just trying to recreate [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4)? It's free...

Comment: We have additional functionality which we are adding to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41189/discussion-between-rajesh-and-adrian-larson).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the problem is "selecting too many fields", you can break the set of fields up into two or more lists and do two or more queries:

```
SObject[] sobs1 = [select Id, FieldA, FieldB, ... from ... order by Id];
SObject[] sobs2 = [select Id, FieldM, FieldN, ... from ... order by Id];
```

and then where you want to consume that data relate the two lists by index or Id value.

Answer (score 1):

Often you will need to frame a question as "build" vs. "buy" and try to justify why you need custom development or acquire the necessary budget. Here, the product ([Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4)) is free, so the decision seems obvious.

If you want to add some functionality that is not included in Field Trip, you can build on top of it. Send out the results via `Scheduled Report`. You can write one on `Field Analysis` and even filter out fields you want to ignore. Or write a job to compile and email the results if you need something more complex (or just don't want to set up the reports).

My assessment is that a team of really smart people has already tackled the most complex piece of what you are trying to accomplish. Take advantage of that.